# Pressure Tab Not Shown

Tags: cloth-simulation

[image]

I cannot find the pressure tab in the cloth attrributes section. I was trying to make a couch and was going to add pressure to the pillow. But, I could not find it anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

You are using an older version of blender that pre-dates 2.82

The new cloth simulator you are looking for comes with blender 2.82 and higher